# Make my own FIFO Queue class for my own class object to fill it?

Tags: java, class, object, queue, fifo

I am trying to make a FIFO Queue that is filled with my own class object. 
I found this example but if I replace < E > with < PCB > it does not work:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;


public class SimpleQueue<E> {

private LinkedList<E> list = new LinkedList<E>();


 public void put(E o) {
    list.addLast(o);
     }


  public E get() {
     if (list.isEmpty()) {
          return null;
      }
   return list.removeFirst();
   }


   public Object[] getAll() {
     Object[] res = new Object[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
      res[i] = list.get(i);
      }
   list.clear();
    return res;
 }



    public E peek() {
      return list.getFirst();
      }


  public boolean isEmpty() {
     return list.isEmpty();
    }


  public int size() {
    return list.size();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Generics should be "general". Wanting to change the type variable name to `PCB` makes it seem like you have a specific type in mind as a parameter. In any case, you probably just made a type when you did your search-and-replace; there's nothing syntactically wrong with using "PCB", it just looks ugly.

Comment: How do you replace `E` with `PCB`?

Comment: "It doesn't work". What doesn't work? Doesn't it compile?

Comment: And if it doesn't compile, whats the errormessage and where in the code does the error manifest. If it compiles what behaviour are you seeing? We can't really help you with your problem if don't give us the necessary information. I would suggest reading http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html as a reference on how to ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

`E` is a type parameter. In simple terms, you can consider it as a 'template' which can be used to create a queue that can hold instances of one particular class.

You can create a queue of your `PCB` objects as follows:

```
SimpleQueue<PCB> queue = new SimpleQueue<PCB>();
```

[Java Generics FAQs](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) is a good resource if you want to learn more about Java generics.

Comment: @Luron: you said "...if I replace < E > with < PCB >..." which I took to mean that you actually replaced `<E>` with `<PCB>` in the Java source for `SimpleQueue`. If you instantiated `SimpleQueue` as in my answer, why does it not work? I've tried it and it seems to work (a `put` and `get` seem to work OK, but I may be missing something). Do you have a compilation error or stack trace?

Comment: @Luron: sorry, I don't understand. I've copied your `SimpleQueue` class into a new Java source file, and it compiles fine. I'm also able to instantiate it as shown in my answer. What problem do you have? A compilation error?

Comment: @Luron: So what is the error? Are you getting a compiler error message? Does it give some error when you run it? The code looks valid, and if Richard says he ran it and it works, than the problem is not blatant. You'll need to give us more information on the problem, not just "it didn't work".

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyQueue{

    int arr[]=new int[10];
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    public void inn(int a)
    {
        System.out.println("You hava entered :"+a);
        arr[i]=a;
        i=i+1;
    }
    public int out()
    {
        return arr[j++];

    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        MyQueue q=new MyQueue();
        q.inn(4);
        q.inn(3);
        q.inn(46);
        q.inn(44);
        q.inn(43);
        System.out.println(q.out());
        System.out.println(q.out());
        System.out.println(q.out());
        System.out.println(q.out());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The sun's generic tutorial says following:

> We recommend that you use pithy
>   (single character if possible) yet
>   evocative names for formal type
>   parameters. It’s best to avoid lower 3
>   case characters in those names, making
>   it easy to distinguish formal type
>   parameters from ordinary classes and
>   interfaces. Many container types use
>   E, for element, as in the examples
>   above.

So, it can't be the problem that you changed it to `PCB`.

But if `PCB` is the only class of which you want to store objects, you don't have to create a generic class. Just remove `<PCB>` from your class definition line and replace all `E`'s with `PCB`:

```
public class SimpleQueue
{
    LinkedList<PCB> list = new LinkedList<PCB>();

    ....

    public PCB peek()
    {
        return list.getFist();
    }
}
```